# How to write a cronTab expression to run a script every second Monday in a month at specified time?

Tags: cron

My instance is scheduled to run every 7 days in a month. I have two programs P1 and P2 of which P1 runs every Monday at 4PM and P2 runs every second Monday day at 00:10 midnight.

My instance crontab expression (to turn it on every 7th day is):

`0 0 * * MON`

My crontab expression for P1 is : (to run P1 at 16:00 hours every 7th Day)

`30 16 * * MON`

Now I am trying to figure out how to write crontab expression to run every second monday.

Any advise for the same?

Here is how my structure looks:

Today is 7th May : Friday

Next:

```
Machine On time: 10th May 00:00 (Monday)
P1 On time: 10th May 16:30 hrs
P2 On time: NA
```

Next:

```
Machine On time: 17th May 00:00 (Monday)
P1 On time: 17th May 16:30 hrs
P2 On time: 17th May 00:10 hrs
```

Next:

```
Machine On time: 24th May 00:00 (Monday)
P1 On time: 24th May 16:30 hrs
P2 On time: NA
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this - `0 0 12 ? * 1#2`. This cron job will run on the second Monday of the Month, at noon.

You can do something similar to this.
Or if you want to explore some more types, here are a few useful resources where you can find your answer -

https://crontab.cronhub.io/

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Why 12 in day's place? Didn't get that part.

Comment: Your expression seems to be At 12:00 PM, on the second Monday of the month. I am more interested in running it on every 2nd monday and not just second monday of month.

Sorry if I confused you, but what I am looking for is 2nd Monday then fourth monday and so on

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Its at 12:00 PM on the second Monday of the month. I also got your question. Will let you know if I'm able to come up with some cron-expression for your requirement.